# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type ... with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, dependency-injection, weld

I got a stupid problem when deploying my Java Application on JBoss. Before I changed my source code using an interface class everything was fine. So here is my problem:

```
public interface FWInterface {
   public FWResult process(FWRequest fwRequest, FWResult fwResult,
                           Integer commitRows) throws Exception;
}
```

...

```
@Stateless
public class FWHandlerSqrMind extends FWHandlerDefault implements FWInterface {

   public FWResult process(FWRequest fwRequest, FWResult fwResult, Integer commitRows)
                   throws Exception {
                ... some JavaCode here
   }
}
```

This ends up with the following Error at deployment on JBoss 7.1:

> 10:05:34,838 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."mdk-exchange-1.1.0.war".WeldService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."mdk-exchange-1.1.0.war".WeldService:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied
>   dependencies for type [FWHandlerAufTracking] with qualifiers
>   [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject
>   de.mdkbw.exchange.filewatcher.FWMain.fwhAufTracking]  at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_15] Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied
>   dependencies for type [FWHandlerAufTracking] with qualifiers
>   [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject
>   de.mdkbw.exchange.filewatcher.FWMain.fwhAufTracking]  at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
>     at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)

If I remove the implementation everything is ok. Could anybody tell me what the problem is? Am I too stupid?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How do you inject your bean? Like that?

```
@Inject
private FWHandlerSqrMind handler;
```

If so could you try to inject it like that:

```
@Inject
private FWInterface handler;
```

Comment: In general it's better to inject the interface, as it allwows the dependency injection framework to return a different implementation, for example using proxies. I haven't worked with JBoss in a long time so I'm afraid I don't have a deeper explanation. As a rule of thumb always use the least specific interface for injection

Answer (score 7):

Do you have  META-INF/beans.xml or WEB-INF/beans.xml file in your class path?

Answer (score 6):

Missing beans.xml was the problem in my case (WildFly 8.2.0).
Just placing a simple beans.xml like the following solved this problem:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd" />
```

Comment: In my case as well, adding `bean.xml` solved the unsatisfied dependencies issue.